# UIKit Accordion для Joomla 4 всегда закрытый первый пункт, как?

Tags: joomla, uikit, accordion

UIKit 2.27.4 - да, именно эта версия, разраб по своим соображения не хочет пока обновлять до более высокой версии.
Шаблон на Gantry 5, с встроенным UIKit.

Суть такова: хочу в тексте статьи запихать текст под аккордеон, не используя сторонних расширений. Использую код из документации:

```
<div class="uk-accordion" data-uk-accordion="">
    <h3 class="uk-accordion-title">Item 1</h3>
    <div class="uk-accordion-content">Lorem ipsum bla-bla-bla.</div>

    <h3 class="uk-accordion-title">Item 2</h3>
    <div class="uk-accordion-content">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum bla-bla-bla.</div>
</div>
```

Этот код всегда делает открытым 1-й пункт, а мне надо сделать пункты всегда закрытыми. Добавлял следующие варианты:

```
 1. data-uk-accordion="{collapsible: false; multiple:false;}"
 2. data-uk-accordion="{collapse: false;}"
 3. data-uk-accordion="{collapsible: false; multiple:false; showfirst: false;}"
 4. data-uk-accordion="{collapsible: false;}"
```

ни один не сработал, пункт всё равно остается открытым. Обновлять отдельно UIKit боюсь, т.к. могут слететь эффекты в других местах. Подскажи, пожалуйста, почему не работает?